# Creating folder using bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a bat file which creates a new folder using current date and time for folder name. 
I came up with the following:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:," %%i in ("%TIME%") do md %DATE%-%%i.%%j.%%k
```

Does this code has any flaws? Is there an easier / more natural way to do it?

Comment: By the way, this creates two directories here. Using quotes (md "%DATE%-%%i.%%j.%%k") would be better.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a substring and the built-in %DATE% and %TIME% variables to do this:

```
@echo OFF

:: Use date /t and time /t from the command line to get the format of your date and
:: time; change the substring below as needed.

:: This will create a timestamp like yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%

@echo TIMESTAMP=%TIMESTAMP%

:: Create a new directory
md "%1\%TIMESTAMP%"
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, this approach seems more natural to me

Comment: Very helpful!  Though, it should be noted that the above code's usage assumes a single parameter: the destination location of the new folder.  If you use that as is, you'll have a timestamped folder in the root of whatever drive you launched from.

Answer (score 6):

I use this bat

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%i
set Month=%%j
set Year=%%k
)

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%i in ('time /t') do (
set Hour=%%i
set Minute=%%j
set Second=%%k
)


md %1\%Year%-%Month%-%Day%
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that time /t won't work if command extensions are disabled, but I guess this doesn't really bother you. (See http://www.pc1news.com/disabling-command-processor-extensions-824.html for reference)

Comment: I don't know much about bat scripting, I just wanted bat that creates a folder with current date, but thank you for the information.

Comment: The second for loop doesn't display the seconds on my computer, because time /t output is just 8:12 for me (no seconds).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get many of the above to work, used the original posters command successfully though.

Here's my version:

> for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:/" %%i in ("%DATE%") do set DATESTAMP=%%i.%%j.%%k
>
> @echo Directory will be made with this name:
>
> @echo backup.%DATESTAMP%
>
> md backup.%DATESTAMP%
>
> @echo Directory made, now proceeding with file copy...
>
> @echo please ensure PC doesn't have E-mail or any documents open.
>
> pause
>
> cd backup.%DATESTAMP%
>
> md "Shared Documents"
>
> xcopy "c:\documents and settings\all users\documents\documents" "Shared Documents" /E /C /I /H /Q
>
> @echo in Documents Complete.

etc :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why a simple %time% does not work is because its separated by : which is not allowed in batch scripting. But this one should work fine:

It works very well for me.

```
Rem Get Day,Mth & Year from %Date%
set Day=%Date:~0,2%
set Mth=%Date:~3,2%
set Yr=%Date:~6,4%
REM Get Hour and Min from %Time%
set Hour=%Time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set Min=%Time:~3,2%

mkdir %date%-%hour%.%min%
```

Answer (score 0):

have you not just tried to make a new new folder maker using date and time saved as new_folder_maker.bat  with this code

```
:start
@echo off
md new_folder_%date%_%time%
exit
```

Comment: _have you not just tried_ your own code? Obviously it can't work, as `%time%` contains colons and in some minor countries the date contains slashes, both aren't valid in path names

Comment: Indeed it depends on the Time and Date settings

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (modified off lopkiju's).  It creates a folder using a datestamp.  If a folder by that name already exists, append an integer to it to make it unique.  Put this in a .bat file and pass in the path to the parent folder.
Tested in Windows 7 Home Premium x64.

```
REM Create a folder using the current date.  If such a folder already exists, append a number to make it unique.
@ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%j
set Month=%%i
set Year=%%k
)

set Path=%~1\%Year%-%Month%-%Day%
set /a inx=2

:LOOP
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%" GOTO CREATE
set Path=%~1\%Year%-%Month%-%Day% (%inx%)
set /a inx+=1
if %inx% gtr 9 goto :END REM Eh, giving up.
goto LOOP
:END

:CREATE
md "%Path%"
:END
```

Comment: can you provide a resource that explains this step by step please? I used the help in the command prompt and it's a little hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

You may take advantage of [GNU sh-utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) using `date.exe`'s format specifiers:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('date.exe +%%Y-%%m-%%d.%%H-%%M') do @set dd=%%a
md %dd%
```

This solution is especially important for those with **localized versions** of Windows.

`for` loop runs once, but it is needed since there's no simpler way to assign a variable with the the value taken from command's output.

Use `date --help` for the full list of format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

this works pretty well for me

```
dkdir foldername

cd foldername

dkdir %date% %time% 

cls
```