# Tricky .bat to create folders, files in bulk.

Tags: date, batch-file, directory

Can someone please help me **creating two .bat files** that help me automate my task at hand? 
This is a great one to start, but I need something more complex:
[Creating folder using bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574777/creating-folder-using-bat-file)

1, I would like to create in `this folder`, multiple folders that have names with a date format in them (example '2014_01_01_Logs', '2014_01_02_Logs', and so on) between a `start date` and an `end date`. Each folder should have one file in it, similarly with the date format (example '2014_01_01_primary_log.xml' in  '2014_01_01_Logs', '2014_01_02_primary_log.xml' in  '2014_01_02_Logs', and so on).

2, The second .bat file should set the date in the file system of both the .xml files and the folders to the date in question. The time part can be set to 23:59:59. (For example '2014_01_01_primary_log.xml' should have last modified date of 2014.01.01 35:59:59, the same as in  '2014_01_01_Logs') This also should have the parameters `this folder`, `start date` and an `end date`.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. Sziro

Comment: What Joe said.  What have you tried so far?  What results have you obtained?

Comment: I can create folders and files. I have linked a solution to that. I need a cycle, that will go from start date to end date, create cycle variables that can be supplied to the creating methods, etc.

Comment: If you post your code, we may help to complete it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch code below generate the range of dates given a `start date` and `end date`. This version does not manage leap years, but the necessary modification for that is simple.

**EDIT**: *Leap year management added*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Parameters: startDate endDate in YYYY/MM/DD format
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%1") do set /A year=%%a, month=1%%b, day=1%%c
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%2") do set /A endY=%%a, endM=1%%b, endD=1%%c

set m=100
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set daysPerMonth[!m!]=1%%a
)

set /A leap=year%%4
:nextMonth
   set lastDay=!daysPerMonth[%month%]!
   if %month% equ 102 if %leap% equ 0 set lastDay=129
   if %year%%month% equ %endY%%endM% set lastDay=%endD%
   for /L %%d in (%day%,1,%lastDay%) do (
      set DD=%%d
      echo %year%_%month:~1%_!DD:~1!
   )
   set /A month+=1, day=101
   if %month% gtr 112 set /A year+=1, leap=year%%4, month=101
if %year%%month%%day% leq %endY%%endM%%endD% goto nextMonth
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test 2013/12/30 2014/03/02
2013_12_30
2013_12_31
2014_01_01
2014_01_02
2014_01_03
. . . .
2014_01_29
2014_01_30
2014_01_31
2014_02_01
2014_02_02
2014_02_03
. . .
2014_02_26
2014_02_27
2014_02_28
2014_03_01
2014_03_02
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from here is close to a good: https://superuser.com/questions/483045/how-do-i-write-a-batch-script-to-generate-folders-for-each-month-day-and-year

Still it would be better if some calendar function existed.

```
@echo off & setlocal
set year=%1
if "%year%"=="" set /p year=Year? 
if "%year%"=="" goto :eof
set /a mod=year %% 400
if %mod%==0 set leap=1 && goto :mkyear
set /a mod=year %% 100
if %mod%==0 set leap=0 && goto :mkyear
set /a mod=year %% 4
if %mod%==0 set leap=1 && goto :mkyear
set leap=0

:mkyear
call :mkmonth 01 Jan 31
call :mkmonth 02 Feb 28+leap
call :mkmonth 03 Mar 31
call :mkmonth 04 Apr 30
call :mkmonth 05 May 31
call :mkmonth 06 Jun 30
call :mkmonth 07 Jul 31
call :mkmonth 08 Aug 31
call :mkmonth 09 Sep 30
call :mkmonth 10 Oct 31
call :mkmonth 11 Nov 30
call :mkmonth 12 Dec 31
goto :eof

:mkmonth
set month=%1
set mname=%2
set /a ndays=%3
for /l %%d in (1,1,9)        do mkdir %year%\%year%-%month%-%mname%\%year%-%month%-0%%d
for /l %%d in (10,1,%ndays%) do mkdir %year%\%year%-%month%-%mname%\%year%-%month%-%%d
```

The second one:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set year=%1
if "%year%"=="" set /p year=Year? 
if "%year%"=="" goto :eof
set /a mod=year %% 400
if %mod%==0 set leap=1 && goto :mkyear
set /a mod=year %% 100
if %mod%==0 set leap=0 && goto :mkyear
set /a mod=year %% 4
if %mod%==0 set leap=1 && goto :mkyear
set leap=0

:mkyear
call :mkmonth 01 Jan 31
touch -t %year%01012359 %year%\%year%-01-Jan
call :mkmonth 02 Feb 28+leap
touch -t %year%02012359 %year%\%year%-02-Feb
call :mkmonth 03 Mar 31
touch -t %year%03012359 %year%\%year%-03-Mar
call :mkmonth 04 Apr 30
touch -t %year%04012359 %year%\%year%-04-Apr
call :mkmonth 05 May 31
touch -t %year%05012359 %year%\%year%-05-May
call :mkmonth 06 Jun 30
touch -t %year%06012359 %year%\%year%-06-Jun
call :mkmonth 07 Jul 31
touch -t %year%07012359 %year%\%year%-07-Jul
call :mkmonth 08 Aug 31
touch -t %year%08012359 %year%\%year%-08-Aug
call :mkmonth 09 Sep 30
touch -t %year%09012359 %year%\%year%-09-Sep
call :mkmonth 10 Oct 31
touch -t %year%10012359 %year%\%year%-10-Oct
call :mkmonth 11 Nov 30
touch -t %year%11012359 %year%\%year%-11-Nov
call :mkmonth 12 Dec 31
touch -t %year%12012359 %year%\%year%-12-Dec
touch -t %year%01012359 %year%
goto :eof

:mkmonth
set month=%1
set mname=%2
set /a ndays=%3
for /l %%d in (1,1,9)        do touch -t %year%%month%0%%d2359 %year%\%year%-%month%-%mname%\%year%-%month%-0%%d
for /l %%d in (10,1,%ndays%) do touch -t %year%%month%%%d2359 %year%\%year%-%month%-%mname%\%year%-%month%-%%d
```