# Batch script to add information to last folder and its content

Tags: batch-file, build-automation

**Pre-information**

- The folder/files sit on a server: `\\192.168.1.1\xxx`
- The script will be located in the folder where the process needs to take place
- Script will be executed via a shortcut on a computer's desktop with a keyboard shortcut
- OS - Win 7 / Win 2008 R2

**Requirments**

I would like the script to do the following.

1. Pop up a window in the center of the screen with large text saying "In Process".
2. Locate the last folder created in the folder where the script is located. Copy the file name into memory to be used for later. The folders name is the time when it was created.
3. Add " - ESFGB" at the end of the folder e.g `Before - "Test Folder"` - `After - "Test Folder - ESFGB"`
4. Paste the folders name at the end of contents of the files inside the folder. e.g
   `Before - "Test.pxc"` - `After - "Test - 22-06-2014-00:58:04.pxc"`
5. Copy the files to a location which is specified in the script `\\192.168.1.1\xxx\123`
6. Once copied, a message stating that the file has been copied (percentage progress would be great
7. Press enter to close world

This is what I have research but I ma not good at putting it all together:

Get last created directory batch command [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519389/get-last-created-directory-batch-command)

Creating folder using bat file [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574777/creating-folder-using-bat-file)

I am presently trying it out.

Here is the first part of the code however I am not sure how to get it to rename all the files inside that folder that has been found.

```
     @echo off

mode con: cols=50  lines=20
color a
REM Locate the last folder created in the folder where the script is located.
FOR /F "delims=\" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof
:found

echo Most recent subfolder: "%a%"

echo Most recent subfolder: "%a%"
cd %a%
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%a-%a%"
cd ..\
ren "%a%" "%a% - ESP"
pause
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for people to write code for you. Please try to write your own code, then come here with problems you experience along the way, and include any code you have.

Comment: @unclemeat Indeed, that was the idea. I stated I am presently trying it out, still am.

Comment: This question reads as though you're asking for code. You haven't included any of your own code.

Comment: @unclemeat No not at all, just stating the objectives of my goal. I am working on the code and I shall include it. Might have been a better idea to do it all at once, noted for next time.

Comment: No worries. It just makes the question easier to answer, as well as compliant with the sites rules.

Comment: @unclemeat You are right, understood. Thank you. (I love when are people are polite)

Comment: The message that comes up is that the system cannot find the specified location.

Comment: @unclemeat How would I get the rename command to rename for the 4th letter in. Thank you. `for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%a-%a%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last two lines don't seem to match what you are trying to do.

set %a%=file will create a variable whose name is the content of %a% and set it to value "file", this is then not used. The rename command will then just try and rename a file called "file".

If you are trying to just rename the sub dir found try:

> `ren %a% "%a% - ES123"`

To then loop through the contents of that sub-dir renameing the files in it use a similier FOR /F loop to the one you used with a rename command to rename each file in the body of the loop. Can use batch variable substitution commands to strip extension and put it back for each rename, e.g. %~nI to get filename bit, %~xI to get extension (for a variable %I%).

This is useful link for info on FOR and variable substitution:

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I have used the code `ren %a% "%a% - ES123"` however, it just says the the system cannot find the specified file. I am just trying to rename the folder that has been found as add -ES123 at the end of it. Thank you

Comment: My folder has a space in the file name, if I remove the space it all works however with the space it does not work at all.

Comment: put quotes round the %a% then so: ren "%a%" "%a% - ES123"

Comment: Not as such, e.g. Here is a folders name: 2014-06-23 15h25m99s however it only show the `echo` as 2014-06-23 which means it is not reading the full folder name.

Comment: I have it now `"delims=\"`. Progressing.

Comment: ah, yes. The FOR will split the file names by whitespace assigning first token to %i by default, changing the delim prevents that. Could also set no delim with "delims="

Comment: Now that I have the latest folder created renamed with ESP at the end of it, how may I rename all the files inside that folder by adding the folders name to the end of them. The internet does not show much about that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For renameing the files in the subdir whilst keeping the exisiting file extension, which I think is your requirement, you can use the variable substitution modifiers to get the name and extension seperatly then build your new file name.

Would be best to use more meaningful names for your varaiables, so have used %subdir% below instead of your %a%

```
....
cd "%subdir%"
for %%i in (*) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni - %subdir%%%~xi"
```